# How to call a method inside the operator> method if the methord called needs to change data members?

Tags: c++, data-structures, operator-overloading

I built my own minHeap which requires me to overload the operators of all the classes i want to push to it. I have  a Region class with a method called findSmallestCity. this method loops through road objects (each which have two cities) and then returns the smallest city in any road inside the region.

my comparison operators need to know which of the two Regions has a smaller indexed city (cities are integer values) because if two regions have the same number of roads it determines "smaller" by which one has a lower indexed city in it.

Here is the code for the operators and findSmallestCity:

```
int Region::findSmallestCity(){
    curRoad = head;

    int smallestCity = curRoad->getCityA();

    while(curRoad != 0){
        if(curRoad->getCityA() <= smallestCity) smallestCity = curRoad->getCityA();
        if(curRoad->getCityB() <= smallestCity) smallestCity = curRoad->getCityB();
        curRoad = curRoad->nextRoad;
    }

    return smallestCity;

}

bool operator<( const Region &lhs, const Region &rhs)
{
    if(lhs.numRoads < rhs.numRoads) return 1;
    else if(lhs.findSmallestCity() < rhs.findSmallestCity()) return 1;
    else return 0;

}

bool operator>( const Region &lhs, const Region &rhs)
{
    if(lhs.numRoads > rhs.numRoads) return 1;
    else if(lhs.findSmallestCity() > rhs.findSmallestCity()) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

bool operator<=( const Region &lhs, const Region &rhs)
{
    if(lhs.numRoads < rhs.numRoads) return 1;
    else if(lhs.findSmallestCity() < rhs.findSmallestCity()) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
bool operator>=( const Region &lhs, const Region &rhs)
{
    if(lhs.numRoads > rhs.numRoads) return 1;
    else if(lhs.findSmallestCity() > rhs.findSmallestCity()) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to get around the errors i am getting that say:

```
error: passing ‘const Region’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int Region::findSmallestCity()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|
```

Comment: Logically, `operator<` should not change the observable state of the object.

Answer (score 2):

Just make your method const:

```
int Region::findSmallestCity() const { ... }
```

this lets the compiler know that you don't intend to change the Region, so it is safe to use with const Region objects.

Comment: This worked! Wow i cannot believe it was so simple. I had to use a new variable on the inside of findsmallestCity instead of curRoad (which was a member variable) but after that was changed it worked fine!